# Group items in array and count repeated items

Tags: php, arrays

in my script i use curl to get json data from an url.

in the response i got this results:

> product1 - 1 product2 - 1 product3 - 1 product1 - 3 product4 - 1

i need to group the products and get the total of items:
ie.

> product1 - 4 product2 - 1 product3 - 1 product4 - 1

here is some of my code:
this code output all the items:

```
        $json = json_decode($result,true);




   foreach($json as $prop => $value){

   foreach ($value as $id) {


     foreach ($id['line_items'] as $code) {


         echo $code['sku'].' - '.$code['quantity'].'<br>';

         }


       }

       }
```

thank you

Comment: Are you getting just a string back like shown? Or are you actually getting JSON back? Because how do you get array with the same keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a counter assoc array and then use `+=` to save the quantities.

```
  $totals = array();
  $json = json_decode($result,true);
  // ... snip ...
  foreach ($id['line_items'] as $code) {
     $sku = $code['sku']
     $quant = $code['quantity'];
     if (!isset($totals[$sku])) {
        $totals[$sku] = 0;
     }
     $totals[$sku] += intval($quant);
  }
```